# LED specs: difference between nominal power and power consumption?

Tags: led

I have have a question regarding the technical specs of a LED. In the specs are two values given:

- Nominal power: 30W
- Power consumption: 6,6W

What is the difference between these two values? The meaning of the values itself is clear, but why are there two of them? From what value can I calculate the overall current consumption?

Comment: LED or LED bulb or LED light fixture?  Big difference.  Link to the data in question, preferably on a datasheet.

Comment: It probably just means that it supplies the luminance of a 30 W incandescent light bulb but only consumes an actual 6.6 W of power to do it. Not especially good.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is a LED bulb (sadly only in german or danish and no datasheet): https://www.lumeri.de/lumeri-smd30-fsp.html)

Comment: @ben That's not a particularly high efficacy bulb. At their peak, incandescent bulbs maxed out at about 16 lumens per watt. So you'd expect less than or about 480 lumens in a 30 W incandescent bulb. If you divide that by 6.6 watts, you get 73 lumens per watt. This is well within the usual LED light bulb's efficacy. However, the higher efficacy white LEDs are as good as 135-140 lumens per watt. So it's not an exceptional bulb, but more of an average one.

Comment: I guess the low lumens/watt ratings comes from the fact, that it has additional UV and IR chips to deliver a broader spectrum.

Comment: Oh yes that's an LED grow light.  You probably won't get the best results with the bulb ones.  Trying to compare them between websites is extremely difficult, but in general, you're probably better off with the fixture type in terms of cost effect.

Comment: If you're just trying to spoil a deserving house plant, this type of screw in bulb isn't a bad idea, but they aren't particularly cost effective because you need a socket per bulb and a lightbulb shape isn't ideal for cooling.  If you end up trying to grow something substantial and you decide you need the equivalent of a larger grow light, for that you'd want a large fixture shaped to cool easily rather than a bunch of these bulbs.

Comment: Spending 10+ euros on what is essentially a light bulb with a few (mostly useless) UV/IR LEDs stuck on isn't a great idea. A conventional LED bulb will work just as well (which is to say not very well given that the bulb form factor is poorly suited to grow lights).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback to the efficiency of the grow light bulb. I have two of them in parallel and I can say, it works. The basil and oregano plants are growing fine. If I wanted to make it professionally, I wouldnt buy these bulbs. The initial question was about the current consumption and not the useability :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30W may be equivalent of incandescent bulb with same light intensity. That parameters only for promotional purpose, not real electrical. 6.6W is real consumption.

Comment: thank you very much!